# return TRUE if a column contains only values "D" or empty

Tags: excel

What formula would return TRUE if a column contains only cells with value "D" or empty?

I need this to control the conditional formatting.

Let me briefly tell you how I use it: I keep all translation strings for 9 languages for all GUI texts in my games. I need to control the status of all the texts because I change them frequently and I need to give the changed text out to translation agency.
I use column A to control the status of texts stored in column B. Status D means Done. I use conditional formatting to green the done cells and yellow all the other ones. Now, your formula helps me to highlight the header cell and tells me whether this language has cells waiting for translation or not.

I use this principle for all my text data where I need to track the status. I have macros for setting the conditional formatting of column B based on values in column A if anyone is interested. In my macro is obviously column A the column with the active cell ;-)

EDIT: inspired by the answers below, my final formula is `=(COUNTA(R:R))<>COUNTIF(R:R;"D")+1` where the +1 is for skipping the heading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by counting the number of "D"s and comparing this against the total number of non-blank cells:

```
=(COUNTA(X:X)=COUNTIF(X:X,"D"))
```

This will count the number of non-blank cells in column X, and check whether it is the same as the number of cells in column X that equal "D".

For more complicated uses, you can also modify the second parameter in the COUNTIF to some other conditional statement - see this [link](http://bettersolutions.com/excel/EDH113/LT710711811.htm) for some examples.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the formula solution:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A:A)=COUNTIF(A:A,"D"),TRUE,FALSE)
```

- CountA is number of cells with data
- CountIf tells you how many cells have "D"
- Just wrap in a simple If statement :)

**Please note that COUNTIF is not case-sensitive*

Comment: +1 too for posting nearly simultaneously with the other excel - native solution

Comment: Sure, but you're still saying: if it's true, then it's true, else it's false. Why not remove the pleonastic `IF` construct entirely?

Comment: OP asked that it return TRUE or FALSE I believe.

Comment: Ah I think I was forgetting he was putting this in conditional formatting... Doh

Comment: What I mean is this `=IF(COUNTA(A:A)=COUNTIF(A:A,"D"),TRUE,FALSE)` returns the same thing as the simpler `=COUNTA(A:A)=COUNTIF(A:A,"D")`. The `IF` doesn't add any value.

Comment: Great point! Thanks for clarifying that. The "if" might not add value, but it helps me for some reason read it better, I'm not sure why... :p

Answer (score 2):

I'd put this in cell B1 to check cell A1:

```
=OR(A1="D", A1="")
```

Depending on your locale setting, you might need to `;` for `,` and you might need to use your language's translation of `OR`. Don't blame me :) Blame Misrosoft

To combine a full column, do

```
=AND(B:B)
```

(or perhaps a shorter range: `=AND(B1:B8)` e.g.)

**Edit** put up a link with a demo: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlX1n8WSRNJWdFAwZEpNRGhwdTNucDJ3dWQ1V3owRkE

**Edit** To the comment:

A userdefined worksheet function to do this would roughly look like:

```vb
' untested code - written in browser
Public Function HasOnlyD(rng as Range) As Boolean

     Dim cell As Range
     For Each cell In rng
         If (Not cell.Value = "") And (Not cell.Value = "D") Then
              HasOnlyD = False
              Exit Function 
         End If
     Next          

     HasOnlyD = True
End Function
```

Comment: See [google doc demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlX1n8WSRNJWdFAwZEpNRGhwdTNucDJ3dWQ1V3owRkE) (which you can download as en Excel sheet if you so desire)

Comment: I see your point with this solution. This however requires the extra B column which I want to avoid because I have many of the A columns and this would quite "pollute" my workbook.

Comment: If it is easier then I could define the condition as "column A does not contain one of "A" or "B". But the original condition is more generic.

Comment: You could do so by writing a VBA function. I don't have excel handy so I can't at the moment do it but I'll write a `stub` in the answer in 5 minutes

Comment: There. It has been some 10 yrs since I wrote VBA :) However, there's a worksheet function that you might be able to work with directly (say `=HasOnlyD(A:A)`)

Comment: Nice. I took the liberty of debugging your code: `!=` doesn't exist in VBA.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: very good. The rest worked? Wow! I'm surprised

Comment: @sehe: Disclaimer: I debugged it inside my head!! It worked fine in there. Whoops, compile error... replacing `End Sub` with `End Function`

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use Conditional formating:

- Select your range of data (in my case C5:L10)
- Select formatting with formulae and use this `=(ROWS(C$5:C$10)=COUNTIF(C$5:C$10;"=D")+COUNTBLANK(C$5:C$10))`
- You get a formating like this: [image: The column is formated only it have "D" or empty cells]

Hope this helps

Regards